# A commutator problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, noncommutative-algebra

Let us consider $N \times N$ complex matrices, with $N >2$.
Let D be a diagonal matrix, with 
$$D_{kk} = \sin \left(\frac{2\pi  k}{N}\right), \space  k = 0,..N - 1$$

I am looking for two  hermitian matrices $H_1$ et $H_2$, such that :

$$ [H_1, H_2] = i\space D$$,where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Specific answers for particular low values of $N$ (3, for instance) are also welcome, if no general solution can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show that $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{N}\right)=0$, you may apply the result that every **traceless** skew-Hermitian matrix is the commutator of two Hermitian matrices (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251678/is-every-skew-adjoint-matrix-a-commutator-of-two-self-adjoint-matrices/251804#251804) for a constructive proof).

Comment: Very nice. Thanks

Comment: Well, I have just a little problem : How to find a explicit unitary matrix with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}(1,1,\ldots,1)$ in its last row ?

Comment: @Trimok You may use a Householder matrix. Let $u=\frac1{\sqrt{N}}(1,\ldots,1)^T,\ e_n=(0,\ldots,0,1)^T$ and $w=u-e_n$. Then $U=I-2ww^T/\|w\|^2$ is a real symmetric and orthogonal matrix with $u$ as its last row/column.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the following answer, a possibility for a $N×N$ unitary matrix $U$ having  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}(1,1,\ldots,1)$ in its last row is :

for $\space k = 0,\ldots, N - 2$

$$U_{kk} = - \frac {(N - 1 - k)}{\sqrt{(N - k) (N - k - 1)}}$$

$$U_{kl} =  \frac {1}{\sqrt{(N - k) (N - k - 1)}} for \space l > k$$

$$U_{kl} = 0 \space for \space l < k$$

with : $$U_{N - 1 l} = \frac {1}{\sqrt{N}}, for \space  l = 0,\ldots, N - 1$$