# Linear maps $f: M_n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(AB) = f(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M_n$ be the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Find (with proof) all linear maps $f: M_n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(AB) = f(BA)$ for all matrices $A$ and $B$.

I know that the trace map is one such $f$. The determinant map satisfies $det(AB) = det(BA)$ -- but isn't a linear map, so it doesn't suffice.

Is there a constructive way to find all of the desired linear maps $f$, and show that there are no others ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks (=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $f(AB-BA) = 0$. The set of commutators is the same as the set of trace zero matrices.

Hence $f$ satisfies the condition **iff** $\ker f$ contains all the zero trace matrices.

(Note that this implies that $f$ must be a multiple of the trace operator.)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181430/27978 for some proofs of said fact.

Comment: Marvelous. I didn't know that fact about commutators here. Thanks for your comment. (=

Comment: @michiganbiker898: I added one more important sentence to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that. I believe I can show why that must be true. (=

Comment: Basically the kernel of a non zero real valued linear operator must have codimension one. So either $f$ is zero or it has the same kernel as trace (since we have containment).

Comment: With a multiple of the trace operator, do you mean multiplication by a linear map or multiplication by a scalar?

Comment: @Poseidaan A scalar multiple. If two functionals $g,h$ have the same kernel then one must be a multiple of the other.